# How to add_trace to a plotly object created from ggplotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I want to be able to add a new line/trace to a plotly object. This plotly object will be created from a ggplot object using ggplotly.

I tried 1. creating the plotly object and 2. using add_trace to the plotly object, but I am unable to generate the chart.

I have used ggplot2 for a while now but am new to plotly/ggplotly.

Any help on this is appreciated please.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

structure(list(Date = structure(c(1646697600, 1646784000, 1646870400, 
1646956800, 1647216000, 1647302400, 1647388800, 1647475200, 1647561600, 
1647820800, 1647907200, 1647993600, 1648080000, 1648166400, 1648425600, 
1648512000, 1648598400, 1648684800, 1648771200, 1649030400, 1649116800, 
1649203200, 1649289600, 1649376000, 1649635200, 1649721600, 1649808000, 
1649894400, 1649980800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    PolicyRate = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 
    0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 
    0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 
    0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375), USGG1y = c(1.0522, 1.096, 
    1.1063, 1.0907, 1.2092, 1.1937, 1.1989, 1.1911, 1.1755, 1.2477, 
    1.3147, 1.4839, 1.5409, 1.629, 1.6627, 1.647, 1.5951, 1.595, 
    1.6649, 1.6675, 1.7168, 1.7245, 1.6933, 1.7347, 1.7528, 1.6567, 
    1.6566, 1.6979, 1.6979), USGG2y = c(1.601, 1.682, 1.698, 
    1.75, 1.863, 1.852, 1.941, 1.917, 1.939, 2.118, 2.167, 2.099, 
    2.141, 2.273, 2.331, 2.368, 2.309, 2.337, 2.459, 2.424, 2.517, 
    2.473, 2.463, 2.516, 2.502, 2.407, 2.351, 2.456, 2.456), 
    USGG5y = c(1.778, 1.88, 1.925, 1.948, 2.092, 2.107, 2.182, 
    2.145, 2.144, 2.323, 2.4, 2.32, 2.399, 2.546, 2.558, 2.5, 
    2.44, 2.462, 2.56, 2.552, 2.697, 2.683, 2.709, 2.756, 2.791, 
    2.69, 2.654, 2.788, 2.788), USGG10y = c(1.848, 1.955, 1.99, 
    1.995, 2.135, 2.146, 2.188, 2.173, 2.152, 2.292, 2.384, 2.294, 
    2.374, 2.477, 2.461, 2.397, 2.352, 2.341, 2.385, 2.398, 2.549, 
    2.6, 2.66, 2.705, 2.782, 2.724, 2.702, 2.829, 2.829), USGG30y = c(2.229, 
    2.337, 2.369, 2.356, 2.473, 2.479, 2.455, 2.471, 2.423, 2.519, 
    2.603, 2.486, 2.541, 2.587, 2.542, 2.503, 2.477, 2.45, 2.434, 
    2.458, 2.574, 2.628, 2.681, 2.72, 2.811, 2.813, 2.814, 2.918, 
    2.918)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = "data.frame")

g <- data %>% ggplot() +
     geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=USGG2y))

g
p <- ggplotly(g)
p # works fine until here.

p1 <- p %>% add_trace(x=~Date, y=~USGG5y,yaxis = "y2", mode="lines+markers",type = "scatter")
#doesnt throw up any obvious error"

p1 #this one gives me a blank plotly chart"
```

Answer (score 1):

This one took a while.

Plotly's interpretation (or `ggplot2`'s delivery) was rendered as if the dates were character fields; the axis tick labels were literal labels.
The plot wouldn't render because it presented more of a picture of what `ggplot2` created than a graph.

The way forward

- change the `x` data for the trace to date type data
- update the axes to hold values instead of labels
- add the new trace

There are a few different ways that would work to accomplish this. I've only provided one method.

After creating your `ggplotly` object, update the object. The easiest way to do this is by adding the exact same data from your data frame.

```
p = ggplotly(g)
p[["x"]][["data"]][[1]][["x"]] <- data$Date # change the 'type'
```

With the axes, you could update the object or assign new settings. This method assigns some new settings. Lastly, add the new trace.

```
p %>% layout(yaxis = list(range = c(0, 3), tickmode = "auto"),
             xaxis = list(range =  c(data$Date[1], data$Date[nrow(data)]),
                          tickformat = "%b %d", type = "date", 
                          tickmode = "auto")) %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~Date, y = ~USGG5y)
```

That's it. A few notes on what I did here first...

- `range` sets the lower and upper limit
- `tickmode` has three options

  - it is set to`array` when you use labels
  - I changed it to auto (the labels are ignored)
- for the x-axis, that `range` equates to the min/max dates *in date type format*
- `tickformat`:

  - `%b` is d3 coding for the abbreviated month name
  - `%d` is the day of the month without padding (i.e., Mar 1 versus Mar 01 for March 1st.)
  - there's a space between the two, so that there's a space between the month and day on the axis

[image]